# Using surveyed cross section of river to create typical cross section for entire river length in ArcGIS Pro

Tags: raster, arcgis-pro

I am using ArcGIS Pro.

I have 4 surveyed cross sections that includes survey points. I want to create a typical cross section from these and burn them in the the existing raster such that the river now has a more accurate bathymetry and is still sloped properly.

How would I go about this?